# TikZ: Can a \foreach command run inside decoration = {markings,?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, decorations

Can I use `\foreach` inside of `decoration = {markings, ...`?

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
      \foreach \loc in {.1, .2, ..., 1}{
        mark = at position \loc with {\arrow{latex}},
      }
    }]
    \draw[postaction = decorate] (0, 0) -- (2,3);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code freezes on compilation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't work (at least with your syntax). Though, the `decorations.markings` library provides a different syntax for the `mark` key that offers this.

Simply use

```
mark = between positions .1 and 1 step .1 with {\arrow{latex}}
```

You will face one problem here though, because due to TeX’s imprecision the last step with the value `1` will not be placed. But in this case it is better to place the last arrow as always using `-latex` so that the line gets shorten correctly.

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
        mark=between positions .1 and 1 step .1 with {\arrow{latex}},
    }]
    \draw[postaction = decorate, -latex] (0, 0) -- (2,3);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]